# Oracle ORA01858 Comparing Date to Null

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, oracle11g

Just asking this while I review. I'm sure I am missing something silly. I have a bit of PLSQL comparing a date to null:

```sql
BEGIN
 RETURN CASE
  WHEN (i_date_one IS NULL) THEN  -- ORA01858 occurs here
   i_date_two 
  WHEN (i_date_one = c_min_date) THEN
   NULL
  ELSE
   i_date_one 
 END;
```

The table for both i_date_one and i_date_two have a type of date for this column and yet occasionally the error pops up. I suspect it is due to a row not existing on the table at all but anyone have any tips?

Comment: please add more code, it is not clear what your problem is. You speak about table and show only part of a function body.

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character found where a digit was expected

If - as you said - `i_date_one` and `i_date_two` are `DATE`s, then they can't raise that error. `DATE` column accepts only valid dates.

But, if those are `VARCHAR2` columns which are *supposed to* contain dates, then yes - they can contain something that isn't a valid date, such as `16.o6.2020` (`o6` is a letter "o" and digit "six") and it will raise `ORA-01858`. For example:

```
SQL> declare
  2    my_date     date;
  3    i_date_one  varchar2(20) := '16.o6.2020';
  4  begin
  5    my_date := i_date_one;
  6  end;
  7  /
end;
   *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at line 5


SQL>
```

If that's the case, you'd rather store dates into a `DATE` datatype column. Searching for all possible *wrong* cases might take some time.

---

I don't think that comparing *anything* to `NULL` raises `ORA-01858`; I think you're on the wrong track.

```
SQL> declare
  2    my_date     date;
  3    i_date_one  varchar2(20) := '16.o6.2020';
  4  begin
  5    my_date := case when i_date_one is null then sysdate
  6                    else null
  7               end;
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```